# Keep bottom pointed objects from falling over in Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to simulate cricket stumps in Blender Game Engine. So far, I have completed modeling the stumps and bails. But I am having trouble figuring out how I can keep the stumps steady before I (sort of) launch an object on to it. Just in case you don't know, a set of stumps looks like this:

[Click to see image.](http://www.kookaburra.biz/~/media/images/products/full/cricket/extras/csa501-ash-stumps-front-png.jpg)

Their bottoms are pointed. So how do I keep them standing at first?

I know how to launch an object and make the stumps active rigid bodies. I just want to know how to keep them from falling down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the logic node editor like this on each stump:

[image]

**Explanation**:
At start (Delay node without repeat, Delay = 0) you suspend dynamics (Edit object/Dynamics/Suspend Dynamics)

Then set up a collision node. You must specify the same property for it and the colliding objects! It will activate the restore dynamics and set mass actuators.

So Blender will not calculate dynamics for your stumps until collision. It is a very good performance optimization too. So recommended technique for larger games.

Comment: And what do I put all this logic in? What is Cube.003? On Each Stump?

Comment: Yes on each stamp, and for the ball add a property, mine is "bullet" you can name it by choice, but it must be the same as the collision sensor node property.